# trying to teach negative times negative number positive answer

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I am thinking of negative times negative numbers as:

> $$-3 \cdot 2 = (-2) + (-2) + (-2) = -6$$
>   $$2 \cdot -3 = (-3) + (-3) = -6$$
>   $$-3 \cdot -2 = (-(-2)) + (-(-2)) + (-(-2)) = 6$$

I am trying to teach to someone the methods of negative times negative number which gives us the positive answer. Now you guys please tell me is it correct method or is there any other easy method?

Comment: I think your method is satisfactory. I immagine you dont wnat/need to go beyond things like $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$. I would write $-3\times 2= -2-2-2$ and $2\times -3=(-3)+(-3)$, but yes, I think you did well

Answer (score 3):

I would maybe go with this (complete the pattern):
\begin{align}
2\cdot (-3) &= -6\\
1 \cdot (-3) &= -3\\
0 \cdot (-3) &= 0\\
-1 \cdot (-3) &= \,?
\end{align}
The ancient greek way of viewing multiplication would also solve this. They might explain $3\cdot 2$ somewhere along these lines:

> Lay out a unit length stick alongside a length $3$ stick with end points both at $0$. Now transform the unit stick to a length two stick, and apply the same transformation to the length three stick. The resulting length is $3\cdot 2 = 6$.

Now, for negative numbers, that means laying out the stick the other way from $0$, so the transformation goes from just "stretching" to "stretching and flipping". So still, $(-3)\cdot (-2) = 6$. This is also how multiplication of complex numbers can be viualized, but that's another story (you allow not only for sticks pointing forward and backward, but also in any other direction along the ground).

Comment: I like this answer quite a bit. You could maybe augment it with the fact that a negative number is $n*(-1)$ and then show that they only ever have to remember one negative number multiplication rule: $(-1)^2=1$

Comment: @arthur i am a bit confused pls if you could show me some illustration i mean visually.

Answer (score 0):

$-\cdot-=+$ is required to preserve the properties of $+$ and $\cdot$ when extending it form $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb Z$:
$$0=0\cdot (-1)=(1+(-1))\cdot(-1)=1\cdot(-1)+(-1)\cdot(-1)=(-1)+(-1)\cdot(-1),$$
so $(-1)\cdot(-1)=1$. What properties have been used?